# Cracking the Coding Interview, 6th edition, 2.8

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, big-o, time-complexity

Problem Statement: Given a circular linked list, implement an algoirthm that returns the node at the beginning of the loop.

The answer key gives a more complicated solution than what I propose. What's wrong with mine?:

```
public static Node loopDetection(Node n1) {
    ArrayList<Node> nodeStorage = new ArrayList<Node>();

   while (n1.next != null) {
       nodeStorage.add(n1);
       if (nodeStorage.contains(n1.next)) {
           return n1;
       }
       else {
           n1 = n1.next;
       }
   }

   return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. In a circular linked list, you'd be keeping a reference to the "head" of the list, and the head is the "first" node in the loop, so it is at the beginning of the loop, hence `return head` (O(1)). Or if your only reference is to the "tail" of the list, the head is at "tail.next", again a simple return statement.

Comment: @Andreas: Consider a list A->B->C->D->E->C->D->E->... The start of the loop is at C, not A. And a linked list with a loop doesn't have a tail. Imagine driving on a one way road onto a roundabout without any exits.

Comment: @gnasher729 There is a difference between a [*circular* linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circular_Linked_list), where the last node points back to the first node, and a *corrupt* non-circular (aka open or linear) linked list with a *loop*. I can see now, that the question is not actually about a *circular* linked list, but about a *corrupt* linear linked list, hence my original confusion. The "problem statement" is badly phrased.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your solution is`O(n^2)` time (each `contains()` in `ArrayList` is `O(n)` time) and `O(n)` space (for storing `nodeStorage`), while the "more complicated" solution is `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space.

The book offers the following solution, to whomever is interested, which is `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space:

> If we move two pointers, one with speed 1 and another with speed 2,
>   they will end up meeting if the linked list has a loop. Why? Think
>   about two cars driving on a track—the faster car will always pass the
>   slower one! The tricky part here is finding the start of the loop.
>   Imagine, as an analogy, two people racing around a track, one running
>   twice as fast as the other. If they start off at the same place, when
>   will they next meet? They will next meet at the start of the next lap.
>   Now, let’s suppose Fast Runner had a head start of k meters on an n
>   step lap. When will they next meet? They will meet k meters before the
>   start of the next lap. (Why? Fast Runner would have made k + 2(n - k)
>   steps, including its head start, and Slow Runner would have made n - k
>   steps. Both will be k steps before the start of the loop.) Now, going
>   back to the problem, when Fast Runner (n2) and Slow Runner (n1) are
>   moving around our circular linked list, n2 will have a head start on
>   the loop when n1 enters. Specifically, it will have a head start of k,
>   where k is the number of nodes before the loop. Since n2 has a head
>   start of k nodes, n1 and n2 will meet k nodes before the start of the
>   loop. So, we now know the following:
>   1. Head is k nodes from LoopStart (by definition).
>   2. MeetingPoint for n1 and n2 is k nodes from LoopStart (as shown above). Thus, if we move n1 back to Head and keep n2 at MeetingPoint,
>   and move them both at the same pace, they will meet at LoopStart.

```
LinkedListNode FindBeginning(LinkedListNode head) {
   LinkedListNode n1 = head;
   LinkedListNode n2 = head;

   // Find meeting point
   while (n2.next != null) {
      n1 = n1.next;
      n2 = n2.next.next;
      if (n1 == n2) {
         break;
      }
   }
// Error check - there is no meeting point, and therefore no loop
   if (n2.next == null) {
      return null;
   }
   /* Move n1 to Head. Keep n2 at Meeting Point. Each are k steps
   /* from the Loop Start. If they move at the same pace, they must
   * meet at Loop Start. */
   n1 = head;
   while (n1 != n2) {
      n1 = n1.next;
      n2 = n2.next;
   }
   // Now n2 points to the start of the loop.
   return n2;
   }
```

Comment: Can you also provide the `O(n)` solution in your answer?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen O(n) time and space will just use a HashSet instead of an ArrayList. To get a constant time you need a "trick" described in the book (see edit)

Comment: @amit did you mean constant space in that comment? Constant time is almost certainly impossible.

Comment: @moreON Yes of course, linear time and constant space. The answer itself does mention it correctly however.

Comment: In your first `while` loop, shouldn't it be `while ( n2 != null and n2.next != null)` ? Same for the following `if`.

Comment: Running this on IDE results in infinite loop, at the last step ensure that you set `n2.next = null;` before returning n2 to avoid this.

Comment: Infinite loop for 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5. I found that it for some reason relates to steps count.

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble visualizing what was going on with this algorithm.  Hopefully this helps someone else.

At time t = k(3), p2 is twice the distance from the head(0) as p1, so for them to get back in line, we need p2 to 'catch up' to p1 and it will take L - k(8) 5 more steps to occur. p2 is travelling at 2x the speed of p1.

At time t = k + (L - k) (8), p2 needs to travel k steps forward to get back to k.  If we reset p1 back to the head(0), we know that p1 and p2 will both meet back at k(3, 19 respectively) if p2 is travelling at the same speed as p1.

[image: Linked List graphic]

Answer (score 1):

There is the solution given by amit. The problem is that you either know it or you don't, but you won't be able to figure it out in an interview. Since I have *never* had a need to find a cycle in a linked list, knowing it to me is pointless except for passing interviews. So for an interviewer, stating this as an interview question, and expecting amir's answer (which is nice because it has linear time and zero extra space), is quite stupid.

So your solution is mostly fine, except that you should use a hash table, and you must make sure that the hash table hashes *references to nodes* and not nodes. Say you have a node containing a string and a "next" pointer, and the hash function hashes the string and compares nodes as equal if the strings are equal. In that case you'd find the first node with a duplicate string, and not the node at the start of the loop, unless you are careful.

(amir's solution has a very similar problem in languages where == compares the objects, and not the references. For example in Swift, you'd have to use === (compares references) and not == (compares objects)).

Comment: You are correct, but the reality is that recruiters are going to continue to ask such questions...

Comment: The solution I came up with was using a hash table of references, as you mentioned. I guess the downside to this solution versus the solution given by the book is O(n) space vs O(1) space; both are O(n) time